# Is there a more effective way of coding GDP growth in R rather than using [,] to identify the cells containing the relevant data?

Tags: r, database, indexing

I've been working in the DataCamp Playgrounds, putting into practice the lessons I've completed in the R Data Science Career Track. I've been looking at the Gross Domestic Product Data, specifically Brazil.

I've calculated the GDP growth between 2006 (row 1, column 4 in the database I made named Brazil_2006_2016) and 2010 (row 5, column 4) in two ways.

The first was simply using the standard formula and copying and pasting the data into the space for code:

```
((2208871646202.82 - 1107640325472.35)/1107640325472.35)*100
```

This gives me an answer of `99.4213821405295`, which looks right according the line chart I made using `ggplot()`.
I did attempt to code this process using what I know of indexes in r:

```
Brazil_2006 <- Brazil_2006_2016 [1,4]
Brazil_2010 <- Brazil_2006_2016[5,4]
```

Following up with

```
((Brazil_2010 - Brazil_2006)/Brazil_2006)*100
```

This gave me the same answer, rounded to 4 places.

I want to improve my coding skills so this is the solution I prefer. However, I've seen other examples of calculating GDP growth using more complex coding which tbh I've found impossible to apply - lag() for example. My question is this:

Is there a better (more elegant?) way of coding this calculation?

@RuiBarradas I've added the output of dput(head((Belize_1960_1970) as that is the dataset I'm currently working on.

````
"Belize", "Belize", "Belize"), CountryCode = c("BLZ", "BLZ", 
"BLZ", "BLZ", "BLZ", "BLZ"), Year = c(1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 
1964, 1965), Value = c(28071888.5622288, 29964370.7125857, 31856922.8615428, 
33749405.0118998, 36193826.1234775, 40069930.0699301)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))```
````

Comment: I think your code looks perfectly fine, and straightforward, since you exactly see what's going on, compared to a blackbox such as some `lag` function. Perhaps you better could use the column name instead of number since the latter may change easily if you do some `merge`ing for instance. Using the `with` function you could do, assuming the column is named `gdp`: `with(Brazil_2006_2016, (gdp[5] - gdp[1])/gdp[1])` which might be more concise.

Comment: Thank you! Combining data was my concern too. I'll update my code using your suggestion.

Comment: Very welcome, since the rows may also change also consider something like `with(Brazil_2006_2016, (gdp[year == 2010] - gdp[year == 2005])/gdp[year == 2005])` since you also might have a year column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `growth` function in base R.
The data `gdp` is generated with a exponential growth rate equal to 0.05. The function below computes the growth rate of the entire vector with vectorized instructions.

```r
growth <- function(x, default = 0) {
  n <- length(x)
  y <- (x[-1] - x[-n])/x[-n]
  c(default, y)
}

gdp <- (1 + 0.05)^(1:10)
growth(gdp)
#>  [1] 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: A ```growth``` function sounds great. How would I apply it to the data set ```Brazil_2006_2016```, for example?

Comment: @FirstCosmonaut You would apply it to a column vector. If you edit the question with the output of `dput(head(Brazil_2006_2016))` I'll give an example usage.